# How to minimize wordpress menu and main body gap?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to reduce the space gap after the header menu and before the main content body.

I looked at the massive CSS code of the theme and was a bit confused so decided not to play with the code.

[image]

```
Link - That's Breaking
Theme - Newspaper 7
Blog platform - WordPress 4.2
Website status- OFFLINE
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant CSS and HTML?  It would be more helpful than the screenshot.  Thanks.

Comment: Post the link to your blog much easier to assist then.

Comment: Hiding your question is a lot of space filling words makes it harder for people to help you. Please try and keep to the point as much as possible.